# Seconds_behind_master value keeps on increasing in MySQL replication slave

Tags: mysql-replication

We have a `MySQL 5.0.77` Master-Slave replication. The replication was not properly running for the past few weeks and it was giving `Duplicate entry error 1062`. The `Set Global Skip-counter` option didn't help, so I had to skip the `error no.1062` by adding it to the `/etc/my.cnf` file and then it reported table doesn't exist error in one particular database.

I have then taken a `mysqldump` of that database and restored in Slave last weekend. Then the `Slave IO_Thread` and `Slave_SQL` both started running fine, and it looked like the replication was back on track. The `Seconds_behind_master` value was very high and then it started reducing for the past 4 days.

When I checked the slave replication status today, I found that the `seconds_behind_master` value is keep on increasing since morning. I stopped the `slave IO_Thread` once and then the seconds_behind_master became Null. Then after I started the `IO_thread` the value became the same and kept on increasing.

I see one process is running from morning 
`system user gss-app Connect 9535736 copy to tmp table ALTER TABLE`queue_clicks`ADD INDEX(`puid`)`

Please help me to fix this issue. Thanks.

```
#mysql> show slave status\G;
`*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                Master_Host: 203.x.x.x
                Master_User: replication
                Master_Port: 3306
              Connect_Retry: 60
            Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000990
        Read_Master_Log_Pos: 185674180
             Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000224
              Relay_Log_Pos: 9286354
      Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000774
           Slave_IO_Running: Yes
          Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
            Replicate_Do_DB:
        Replicate_Ignore_DB:
         Replicate_Do_Table:
     Replicate_Ignore_Table:
    Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                 Last_Errno: 0
                 Last_Error:
               Skip_Counter: 0
        Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 472142385
            Relay_Log_Space: 112995681998
            Until_Condition: None
             Until_Log_File:
              Until_Log_Pos: 0
         Master_SSL_Allowed: No
         Master_SSL_CA_File:
         Master_SSL_CA_Path:
            Master_SSL_Cert:
          Master_SSL_Cipher:
             Master_SSL_Key:
      Seconds_Behind_Master: 9533355
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`
```

Comment: MySQL 5.0 reached it's end-of-life [some time ago](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/), and the latest MySQL 5.0 release is 5.0.96 (you have MySQL 5.0.77). Many replication bugs have been fixed since MySQL 5.0.77, and replication performance has improved quite a bit since even MySQL 5.1. There area many reasons for MySQL replication delays in older versions of MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I won't worry about it if the IO and SQL are running, as well as the `Relay_Master_Log_File` is catching up with the `Master_Log_File`. I believe the delay is in the fact that your total relay log file is huge, approx. 105G - `Relay_Log_Space: 112995681998` and considering that the Slave is at 000774 position and master is at 000990 position, there are a total of 214 binary logs of approximately 468M each (105G/214) waiting to be replayed on the slave.

My advice is to keep an eye on the `Relay_Master_Log_File` and make sure that is is going up and catching up with the `Master_Log_File`. I also see that the master host is in a public IP address, is this replication taking place over a public network or slow WAN? That could be introducing a delay, that faster the link the better.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes, the `Relay_Master_Log_File` is catching up with the `Master_Log_file`. Today the `Relay_Log_space` is about 74G. I believe the slave will catchup the master in a week or so.

Comment: Hi Daniel, The replication finally did catch up with the master server two days ago, there were few errors to run few partially completed that I had to run manually and keep an eye on the replication several times everyday. Now, it is 0 seconds behind master. Tested the replication working fine by creating new tables in master database and verified the same created in the slave server. All are fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you stop the IO_Thread and SQL_Thread catches up with the available relay log data, Seconds_Behind_Master will turn to NULL and hence does not reflect the right delay under these circumstances. You can find the right ways to interpret the values of Seconds_Behind_Master under different : https://scalegrid.io/blog/mysql-tutorial-understanding-the-seconds-behind-master-value/

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the exact same issue before.

Please make the following changes to rectify "Seconds_Behind_Master" increasing once slave has started.

Firstly check the "trx" value on slave server

- show variables like '%trx%';

if the value of "innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit" is "1" as below

- Variable_name                             | Value |
- innodb_api_trx_level                      | 0     |
- innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit            | 1     |
- innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit | ON    |

then change this value to "2"

- set global innodb_flush_log_trx_commit = 2;

Once you've changed this in your mysql client also change this in your my.cnf file to ensure that once mysql restarts this value persists.

- vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf

search for "innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1"

and change its value to "2" as well.

This will resolve your "Seconds_Behind_Master" issue.

Comment: This solves for me but I would like to understand why. I believe that shouldn't be an option to be set permanently as well.

Comment: [Here](https://mariadb.com/docs/skysql-dbaas/ref/mdb/system-variables/innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit/)'s an explanation